# calculating probability distribution $Y_1=X_1+X_2,Y_2=X_1-X_2$

Tags: statistics

suppose joint probability distribution $X_1,X_2$ is $f(x_1,x_2)=\displaystyle\frac{x_1x_2}{36},x_1,x_2=1,2,3$. how can  i calculate probability distribution $$Y=\displaystyle\frac{X_1}{X_2}$$ and how can  i calculate joint probability distribution $$Y_1=X_1+X_2,Y_2=X_1-X_2$$

Comment: With $x_1,x_2 \in \{1,2,3\}$ the easiest way is to simply consider all cases.

Comment: Hint: The joint distribution puts masses 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9 respectively, on 9 points of the Cartesian product {2,3,4,5,6}x{-2,-1,0,1,2}.